# How to import a specific worksheet from an excel file?

Tags: vba

I'm using VBA Access 2010. Apparently, the excel file has 13 worksheets and I only need to get the columns from one worksheet. And also, if there's a way to skip the column headers, that would be helpful. Thank you.

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
    stat.Caption = "Import Files"
    Me.Refresh

        If txtFileSource.Value <> "" Then

            Dim strTablename As String
            Dim xlsRpt As New Excel.Application
            Dim xbookRpt As New Excel.Workbook
            Dim iRowCountRpt As Integer
            Dim strRangeRpt As String

            If cmbData.Value = "My File" Then


                Set xbookRpt = Workbooks.Open(txtFileSource.Value)
                iRowCountRpt = xbookRpt.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
                strRangeRpt = "A1:I" & iRowCountRpt
                DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "tbl_Account", txtFileSource.Value, True, strRangeRpt
                xbookRpt.Close
                xlsRpt.Quit


            End If

        cmbData.Value = "Select File"
        txtDestination.Value = ""
        txtFileSource.Value = ""

        Call DeleteImportErrorTables
        Call MsgBox("Import successful!", vbInformation, "Import File")

    End If

stat.Caption = "Ready..."
Me.Refresh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in defining range you can specify the starting row
and you can stay large with the ending row because Access skips the empty rows

```
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "myaccesstable", "myexceldocument", True, "myexcelsheet!A2:X1000"
```